# Session duplication with Play framework 1.2.7

Tags: security, playframework, session-cookies, playframework-1.x

We have a web application that's built on top of Play framework 1. The current version of Play is 1.2.7. It's running on top on Ubuntu 12.04 in an Amazon EC2 instance.

Recently we experienced a peculiar and very worrying behaviour on our test server. There were only a few people using the system: a few developers and a few testers. What happened was that the session cookie of one user was given to two other users. Suppose you have users A, B and C using the system, each logged in as themselves. Suddenly what happens is that all of them seem to be logged in as user A, without any of them doing anything special.

Play is managing its own session cookie. Suppose the session cookie name is configured as XYZ_SESSION. When we saw this behaviour, I was able to inspect the session cookies of users A and B (C was in a different organization and site). The session cookie that B had was 100% same as A had. In this application, the session cookie is used to store user name, email address etc. So in practice, user B was suddenly having the same session as user A. I didn't inspect the cookie of user C, but the verbal report was that he suddenly was logged in as user A.

This was actually a second time this behaviour was observed with this application. The previous time was several months ago, and then a cludgy hack was developed to notice the situation and logout the user in question. However, the hack is not very maintainable or scalable, and we want to get rid of it. And preferably find the root cause for the issue.

The authentication logic of the application is implemented using OpenID4Java. However, when this behaviour occurred, all users were already logged in.

We have a theory on the possible cause of this behaviour. In the application, we have a BaseController class that inherits Play's Controller class and that is used as the base class of all controllers. In the BaseController there is some code that gets and puts to the session container. In the code of that class, the session is referred to as just "session", which means the static field in Play's Controller class. The assumption is that Play's enhancer will enhance the reference to use a ThreadLocal field in Scope.Session class. The enhancing would be done by Play's ControllersEnhancer class. However, when inspecting the code of method enhanceThisClass in ControllersEnhancer, it makes use of CtClass/getDeclaredMethods. In the comments for that method it says "The inherited methods are not included." I don't fully understand how enhanceThisClass gets called, so I'm not entirely sure how solid the theory is.

So, our suspicion is that in practice Play skips enhancing the code in this BaseController class, and the static session field in Play's Controller class gets used as plain as it is, and this combined with suitable scheduling of threads will cause the session duplication!

The problem is quite difficult to reproduce and thus we haven't this far conclusively verified that this is the cause for the behaviour we observed.

Anybody have any insights? Have seen similar behaviour with Play? Able to prove the theory right or wrong?

Answer (score 0):

on my work we use play 1.2.7 in a lot of applications. Last month we see the same issue with Play. Two users with the same session. In our case the app is separated in two modules (catalog and checkout), the catalog was using 1.2.7 and the checkout's module 1.2.4. Because the difference between the modules Play! create the same session in each module and given this session to the users. I don't know if your app has the same structure as our, but if yes, i recommend you see this.

Comment: Hi Elvis! Can you please elaborate a little? Did you find out the exact mechanism how did a user get a wrong session? How did you solve the problem? (And no, in the incident we observed, the application is just one application.)

Comment: Sorry mate.... We dont find the origin of the problem.... our scenario was different of your.... we search the internet through a solution but there isnt any other case on internet.... you have more than one server? You use cache?

Comment: Basically the application is a single application hosted on a single server. I think the theory I describe above is a very probable root cause of the problem, even though it is very difficult to prove it. I think I fixed the problem by refactoring references to "session" in controller base class to "Scope.Session.current()". Question is: do you have a base class for controllers such that it inherits from Play's Controller class, and your individual controller classes inherit from this base class?

Comment: Yes. We have a "central" BaseController (that extends Controller) and any of ours controllers extends this BaseController.

Comment: So in that sense you have exactly the same vulnerability as we did. I would suggest you do the same kind of refactoring that I described in my previous comment to all your Play 1 applications that have the same kind of BaseController.

Comment: @ElvisOliveira Please share your experiences if you try Vesa's suggestion.